# how to fill a div to fit the screen on clicking it and overlay other divs

Tags: jquery

i have set of `<div>` tags with same class name. My aim is when i click on a particular `<div>` i need to maximize its height and width to fill the screen and overlay the rest of `<div>`s . I am using the below code to achieve this

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var isFullscreen = false;
    var d = {};
    var speed = 900; 
    if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
        d.width = $(window).width();;
        d.height = $(window).height();; 
        isFullscreen = true;
    }
    else{ // MINIMIZATION            
        d.width = "300px";
        d.height = "100px";            
        isFullscreen = false;
    }
    i = 0 
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    while(i<=12){
        if(i != id){
            $("i").hide();
        }
        i++;
    }
    $(this).animate(d,speed)
    })
```

So what i did is i gave a **id** to each  in a order from **1 to 12** and trying to hide them except the one clicked. Is this the right way to do this. Apologies for my bad english. Extra Info: I am using Jquery Masonry with fluid layout.

Comment: Take a look at css' z-index command and the value 'absolute' for css' position command.

Comment: What is the shared class name of your 12 divs?

Comment: class="item" used for all 12 <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ns5hD/

Comment: Yes thats what i want...i tried this but i didnt place  $(this).show();... thanks man... if you dont mind can you please tell me how to show them all on clicking once again...